# Two different site-packages in Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, installation, ipython, anaconda, package

I have a fresh install of Anaconda and have created an environment as follows:

```
conda create --name etl
```

I `activate etl` and then `conda install ipython` from within it. It installs everything, but when I go to run ipython I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\etl\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\etl\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\etl\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\etl\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\etl\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 17, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
ImportError: No module named 'decorator'
```

In looking into it, it seems that anaconda has created 2 site-packages within the environment:

[image: First site package]

Note that this site-package is at the root of the environment.

[image: Second site package]

This site package is not in the root, but rather is a sub-directory of `Lib` which is where I would expect it. I'm wondering if I did something wrong or if this is possibly a bug? If I manually move the files in the first site-directory to the second, the error goes away.

Comment: Doesn't anaconda come with ipython?

Comment: have you checked the conda list within environement to see if the package is installed, you maybe have to run this command instead: `conda create --name etl ipython decorator`

Comment: @anishtain4 as noted this is a new environment. The ipython that comes with anaconda is fine/unaffected.

Comment: @hisi thank you for the suggestion, but it did not work - still puts it in a separate directory.